# Como salvar uma lista usando o hibernate?

Tags: java, jsf, hibernate, glassfish

Como salvar uma lista inteira usando o hibernate? Estou tentando salvar uma lista dessa forma:

```
classe.setMinhaLista(minhaLista);
classeDao.salvar(classe);
```

E dessa forma:

```
classe.setMinhaLista(new ArrayList<Objeto>());

for(Objeto obj : minhaLista) {
     classe.getMinhaLista().add(obj);
}

classeDao.salvar(classe);
```

Mas não estou conseguindo de nenhuma das duas formas e o console do glassfish não retorna nenhum erro.

**Entidade MinhaLista**

```
@Entity
public class MinhaLista implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Long idMinhaLista;
private Classe classe;

public void setClasse(Classe classe) {
    this.classe = classe
}

@ManyToOne
public void getClasse() {
    return classe;
}

// Restante dos gets e setter omitidos
}
```

**Entidade Classe**

```
@Entity
public class Classe implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Long idClasse;
private List<MinhaLista> minhaLista;

public void setMinhaLista(List<MinhaLista> minhaLista) {
    this.minhaLista = minhaLista;
}

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "classe",cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
public List<MinhaLista> getMinhaLista() {
    return minhaLista;
}

// Restante dos getters e setters omitidos
}
```

Comment: Você tentou utilizar o Cascade?

Comment: Já, tentei o Cascade ALL, ta salvando a minhaLista, mas tá salvando a lista solta, sem vincular ao objeto classe

Comment: Poderia postar o código das suas entidades ?

Comment: Editei a pergunta com o código

Answer (score 1):

Consegui salvar os itens da lista, todos de uma vez, dessa forma:

1. Salvo cada item da lista solto no banco de dados e adiciono-o a minhaLista

   ```
     objeto.setNome(nome);
     objetoDao.salvar(objeto);
     minhaLista.add(objeto);
   ```
2. Logo em seguida, percorro a minhaLista e atualizo cada objeto, vinculando-o a classe

   ```
     for(Objeto obj : minhaLista) {
         obj.setClasse(classe);
         objetoDao.atualizar(obj);
     }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que a lista esteja sendo salva por estar vazia, se vc preencher os objetos você possa vincular a lista, tbm é bom adicionar obrigatoriedade da propriedade classe na lista, para que o sistema impeça de salvar uma lista sem classe

```
public class Classe {
    private Long id;    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "classe",cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<Lista> minhaLista;
}
```

O cascade PERSIST vai salvar a lista se ela estiver em modo `transient`

```
public class Lista {
    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Classe classe;
}
```

O `Optional=false` vai obrigar o campo a ter uma classe, o NotNull vai adicionar uma validação e se vc estiver usando hibernate validation, ele vai impedir de salvar a transação completa.

E antes de salvar, vc deve fazer a atribuição circular

```
classe.getMinhaLista().forEach(lista->lista.setClasse(classe));
```

Comment: A lista não tá vazia, se eu botar o Cascade ALL ou o PERSIST ela salva, mas sem vincular ao objeto classe

Comment: pontos importante, ela ta salvando a lista sem vinculo porque vc não adicionou a propriedade que torna o vinculo obrigatório, se ela esta salvando sem vinculo ou vc não passou o objeto para vincular ou o objeto esta nulo